# Excel filter to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for a way to automatically filter on a specific column and then for each filter in that column create a new sheet with that data.

I tried looking at using a pivot table and that works to some point if I filter my report on said column and then 'show report filter pages' but using the pivot is not the same as simplifying filtering the data...

Lets say I have 10 columns and 15 rows I specifically want one 'sheet' for each filter result based upon a filter of column H. So if there's no duplicates in column H I'd expect 15 new sheets.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in that case usually is either make a pivot just to get all unique names or I copy-paste (value) the column on a separate column, call `RemoveDuplicates()` and go through that list.

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear - Will add more detail in the post.